# display view in popover

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, popup, autoresize

I display the `detailView.xib` in `UIPopover` in `UIMapView`.

My `DetailView.xib` is :[image]

But when i try to see in popover it shows like:[image]

my code is as follow:

```
 detailsView *popUp=[[detailsView alloc] initWithNibName:@"detailsView_ipad" bundle:nil];


        popView = [[UIPopoverController alloc]initWithContentViewController:popUp];
        popView.delegate =self;

        [popView setPopoverContentSize:CGSizeMake(600, 400)];

[popView presentPopoverFromRect:control.frame inView:self.view permittedArrowDirections:UIPopoverArrowDirectionUp animated:YES];
```

**How can i display the actual xib in `UIPopover`??**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think your problem is content size of popover. Set content size same as of your detail view.

```
[popView setPopoverContentSize:popUp.bounds.size];
```

If you want your view to get fit in whatever content size you are giving, then you need to use Autoresizing or Auto layout(iOS 6+).

Comment: but i don't want to show the the view as actual size in popover

Comment: If you want your view to get fit in whatever content size you are giving then you need to use Autoresizing or Auto layout(iOS 6+).

Comment: how can i enable the auto resizing.

Comment: Can you please help to enable auto resizing??

Comment: Select view in xib->Go to Attributes Inspector->Check Autoresize Subviews checkmark. After that you can set Autoresizing masks from Size Inspector.

Comment: For more details go to "Handling Layout Changes Automatically Using Autoresizing Rules"  section on http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/windowsviews/conceptual/viewpg_iphoneos/CreatingViews/CreatingViews.html